# Is there any way to change image within a time period in react JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the image on the left side in every 3 seconds. Is there any techniques to do it without using react image slider?

I have attached my code here. I have tried to do it using react hooks. I have stored the images inside an array. The images changes perfectly only for first 8-10 seconds.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import bannerImg1 from "../../Assets/Images/bannerProduct1.png";
import bannerImg2 from "../../Assets/Images/bannerProduct2.png";
import { Row, Col, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaCaretRight, FaChevronLeft, FaChevronRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./BannerSlider.css";

const BannerSlider = () => {
  const imageArray = [bannerImg1, bannerImg2];
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(imageArray[count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setImage(imageArray[count]);
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bannerSlider">
      <Container>
        <div className="slider-wrapper">
          <Row className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <Col lg={6} className="banner-image">
              <img src={image} className="w-100 img-fluid" alt="" />
            </Col>
            <Col lg={6} className="banner-text">
              <h2>Where your imagination come true</h2>

              <p>
                {" "}
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
                porro neque odio, at aspernatur explicabo?{" "}
              </p>

              <button>
                Explore More <FaCaretRight className="banner-button-icon" />{" "}
              </button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What, or how, does it stop working after 8-10 seconds? Can you clarify? I'm assuming you run out of images and it throws an error?

Comment: You have 2 image in your array, when count get to 2 it will fail that's why it's stopped

Comment: in your useEffect put setImage(imageArray[count % 2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

From what I can read of your code you've a few issues:

1. The `useEffect` doesn't clear any running timers when the component unmounts.
2. You've closed over the initial `count` state in the interval callback so it's not updating correctly.
3. You don't account for incrementing past the array length.

## Solution

```
// move image array outside component so it's not a dependency
const imageArray = [bannerImg1, bannerImg2, bannerImg3];

const BannerSlider = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Save timer ref and return cleanup function to clear it
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      // Use a functional state update to correctly increment the count
      setCount(count => count + 1);
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);

  // `image` is derived state from the image array and current count
  // Take the count mod array length to get the correct computed index
  const image = imageArray[count % imageArray.length];

  return (
    <div className="bannerSlider">
      <Container>
        <div className="slider-wrapper">
          <Row className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <Col lg={6} className="banner-image">
              <img src={image} className="w-100 img-fluid" alt="" />
            </Col>
            <Col lg={6} className="banner-text">
              <h2>Where your imagination come true</h2>

              <p>
                {" "}
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
                porro neque odio, at aspernatur explicabo?{" "}
              </p>

              <button>
                Explore More <FaCaretRight className="banner-button-icon" />{" "}
              </button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit is-there-any-way-to-change-image-within-a-time-period-in-react-js]

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly. Is there any way to make the change a bit smoothly? just like CSS transition property.

Comment: @MehediHasan Oh, I interpreted your statement about not using a slider to mean you didn't want any sort of transition. Can you describe what you want to change smoothly?

Comment: I want a fade in and out effect while changing the image. Is it possible here?

Comment: @MehediHasan I believe so. It's late for me, but I can tinker around in the morning and update you with a comment with anything.

Comment: @MehediHasan Something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/is-there-any-way-to-change-image-within-a-time-period-in-react-js-forked-ri11b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes something like this.